# Success Alert not Working AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

My success alert isn't working. I'm not sure why. I've tried several different things I found on other questions but nothing has worked so far.

```
$('#tracking-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/includes/tracking.php',
        type:'post',
        data:$('#tracking-form').serialize(),
        success:function(){
            alert("worked");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what does console tell you about the status of this request? 
what is going to happen if you add failure block?

Comment: The console doesn't show anything. How would I add a failure block?

Comment: right after the sucess add this:
error: function() { 
        alert('got error');             
}

Comment: Ok after adding that I get an error in the console. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

Comment: try adding coma after success, like so

success:function(){
            alert("worked");
        },
error: function(){
alert('it did not')
}